# ¿Como aceptar una letra en particular en un input?

Tags: javascript, html, script

¿Es posible que en un input acepte solo una letra en particular? En mi caso, lo que quiero hacer es que el input permita solamente la letra K. Yo se que está ese script para que acepte solo letras, pero existe una forma de permitir una letra en especifico?

Comment: Buenas, te invito a leer [ask] para que tus preguntas sean mejor recibidas por la comunidad, así mismo [mcve].

Answer (score 5):

Creo que esto te serviría:

```js
function onlyK(inputVal) {
  var patt=/^[Kk]+$/;
  if(patt.test(inputVal)){
    document.getElementById('txtK').value = inputVal;
  }
  else{
    var txt = inputVal.slice(0, -1);
    document.getElementById('txtK').value = txt;
  }
  
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="form-text">Solo K</label>
    <input id="txtK" type="text" maxlength="1"
     oninput="onlyK(value)" />
 </div>
```

Lo que hice fue agregar en el handler de `oninput`(Que ocurre cuando el usuario hace una entrada en el input), una invocación a una función que valida mediante expresion regular (Solo para que vieras el mecanismo ideal) si la entrada es "K" o "k"; si lo es, conserva el valor, de lo contrario devuelve la entrada -1 caracter (con el `slice`).

Adicionalmente, coloqué en el html del input un `maxlength`= 1 para evitar que coloquen más de un caractér.

Consideraciones:

1. El slice es solo si deseas tener la funcionalidad para varias posiciones de texto (en este caso "K" es solo 1). Obviamente no aplicaría con el `maxlength`.
2. Dado que en este caso solo quieres validar una letra, es posible que lo puedas hacer sin necesidad de la expresión regular.

Consideraciones:

Comment: Buenas, responder sin dar una explicación del código se toma como una respuesta de baja calidad, por favor agregar una breve explicación de lo que hace este código.

Comment: Tienes razón @VickMuñoz. Ya edité la respuesta. Gracias.